# SIGABRT received due to this code... Why?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, tableview, sigabrt

I am trying to implement a tab bar controller, navigation controller and tableview into an application I'm working on but I am getting a SIGABRT error each time I try to run it and I don't know why and it is rather puzzling me. Below is the code that the console is referencing to (I believe):

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

    // Set up the cell...
NSString *cellValue = [listOfCoffees objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;

return cell;
```

}

...and below is the console:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSCFString tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6a17c00'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00dca5a9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00f1e313 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00dcc0bb -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00d3b966 ___forwarding___ + 966
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00d3b522 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50
    5   UIKit                               0x00091b98 -[UITableView(UITableViewInternal) _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:] + 634
    6   UIKit                               0x000874cc -[UITableView(UITableViewInternal) _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:] + 75
    7   UIKit                               0x0009c8cc -[UITableView(_UITableViewPrivate) _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 1561
    8   UIKit                               0x0009490c -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 242
    9   QuartzCore                          0x016b4a5a -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 181
    10  QuartzCore                          0x016b6ddc CALayerLayoutIfNeeded + 220
    11  QuartzCore                          0x0165c0b4 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 310
    12  QuartzCore                          0x0165d294 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 292
    13  QuartzCore                          0x0165d46d _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 99
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x00dab89b __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 27
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x00d406e7 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 295
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x00d091d7 __CFRunLoopRun + 1575
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x00d08840 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x00d08761 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
    19  GraphicsServices                    0x010021c4 GSEventRunModal + 217
    20  GraphicsServices                    0x01002289 GSEventRun + 115
    21  UIKit                               0x0002ac93 UIApplicationMain + 1160
    22  Affogato                            0x00002259 main + 121
    23  Affogato                            0x000021d5 start + 53
    24  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
)
terminate called throwing an exception
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think that problem is not in that part of code. Where does the debugger stop?

Comment: The debugger stops that this start of the code within the method I put above: NSString *cellValue = [listOfCoffees objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

Comment: If you comment that string, all will be ok?

Comment: Nope, it simply removes the actual contents of the tableview and then once I try to scroll the tableview is still crashes...

Comment: Check all your UITableView data source objects. The problem is in them. Also check release calls to them.

Comment: I have the tableview datasource connected to the CoffeeTableViewController which contains: 

listOfCoffees = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
 
  
 [listOfCoffees addObject:@"Affogato"];
 [listOfCoffees addObject:@"Americano"];
 [listOfCoffees addObject:@"Bicerin"];

Comment: May be `CoffeeTableViewController` was released somewhere?

Comment: Possibly, I've found that as soon as I release my finger from scrolling the tableview, the crash occurs...

Comment: Let's try this: when the app crashes look what variable has address noticed at line `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception`. The list of variables should be displayed on the left of the console. Don't forget to look in `self`.

Comment: Nope, just found that CoffeeTableViewController is not released at all, man this is annoying!

Comment: @Nekto let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2942/discussion-between-dbramhall-and-nekto)

Answer (score 1):

I'm quite sure the actual problem is somewhere else in the code, my guess would be you are using some string variable (possibly selectedCoffee ?) in place of the tableView's delegate.

Comment: The debugged returns the SIGABRT error at this point in the code: NSString *cellValue = [listOfCoffees objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

Comment: What is listOfCoffees ? Probably you should post a more complete example from your code.

Answer (score 1):

The error is in the tableview delegate/datasource. CellForRowAtIndexPath is called by the tableview to query it's UITableViewCell object. Check your delegate/datasource connection.

Answer (score 0):

Set a breakpoint and look where the app crash. Then we could help more.